# Where to download JMXMP?

Tags: java, profiling, jmx, visualvm, jmxmp

I want to profile a Java application with VisualVM, remotely via JMX. Because it's a NAT'ted and firewalled EC2 instance, I can't use the default RMI approach and need to use the optional JMXMP extensions, which I must first download.

> NOTE – IF YOU WANT TO USE A JMXMP CONNECTOR, DOWNLOAD THE JSR 160
>   REFERENCE IMPLEMENTATION FROM
>   , AND ADD THE
>   JMXREMOTE_OPTIONAL.JAR FILE TO YOUR CLASSPATH. YOU WILL FIND EXAMPLES
>   OF USE OF THE JMXMP CONNECTORS IN THE JMX REMOTE API TUTORIAL INCLUDED
>   WITH THE JSR 160 REFERENCE IMPLEMENTATION.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jmx/overview/connectors.html

But when I go to that page, I cannot find the download. In fact, Google cannot find the download. Where can I get these extensions?

Comment: Anyone else think this is a sorry state? Surely remote profiling on a firewalled server shouldn't be this hard?

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjmxremoteoptionaljar.htm

Comment: @BorisPavlović Thanks, I'll try it, but there should be an official download somewhere too, or Oracle/Sun has dropped the ball.

Answer (score 10):

The canonical javax.management:jmxremote_optional appears to have been removed from Maven Central [1].  (I wonder why... legions of Larry's lawyers?)

Fortunately the following appears to be a drop-in replacement which *is* on Maven Central [2]:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.external</groupId>
    <artifactId>opendmk_jmxremote_optional_jar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-b01-ea</version>
</dependency>
```

My JMXMP/TLS code continues to work with this, secured and with authentication on both sides.  May your mileage be equally good. :)

[1] https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/management/jmxremote_optional/1.0.1_04/

[2] https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/external/opendmk_jmxremote_optional_jar/1.0-b01-ea/

Answer (score 4):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/download-jsp-141676.html

...has a download button for **JMX Remote API 1.0.1_04 Reference Implementation**. This links to...

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-plat-419418.html

... which only offers **Java Management Extensions (JMX) Remote API Reference Implementation 1.0.1_03**. So still a bit flaky.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution would to create socks proxy with `ssh -D`. See [this post](https://bowerstudios.com/node/731) for more details. Than start VisualVM and set this proxy in Tools->Options->Network. You don't need to use `-J-Dnetbeans.system_socks_proxy -J-Djava.net.useSystemProxies` on VisualVM command line.

Answer (score 2):

v4.0 came out in May 2013

[jmxremote_optional-repackaged jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.main.external/jmxremote_optional-repackaged)

Answer (score 0):

See OpenDMK at https://github.com/nickman/OpenDMK.
It's a maven build. You need the jmx-optional module.