# How to enable JMXMP in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx, jmxmp, jsr160

[I've downloaded the JMXMP extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412560/where-to-download-jmxmp) and installed them in Tomcat's lib directory. Now, how can I make it use them, i.e. let Tomcat accept JMXMP connections?

- Oracle's examples show how to do it with code, for which I'd have to write my own listener, which I'd rather keep as a last resort.
- [Tomcat's JMX listener](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/listeners.html#JMX_Remote_Lifecycle_Listener_-_org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener) does not seem to include JMXMP support.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I wrote my own JMXMP Tomcat listener. Feel free to use:

```
package webersg.tomcat;

import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;

import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorServer;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorServerFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;

import org.apache.catalina.Lifecycle;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleEvent;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleListener;

public class JMXMPLifecycleListener implements LifecycleListener {

    private int port = 5555;

    private JMXConnectorServer cs;

    @Override
    public void lifecycleEvent(LifecycleEvent event) {

        try {

            // START
            if (Lifecycle.START_EVENT == event.getType()) {

                System.out.println("Start JMXMP on port " + port);

                cs = JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(
                        new JMXServiceURL("jmxmp", "0.0.0.0", port),
                        null,
                        ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer()
                );
                cs.start();

                System.out.println("Started JMXMP");

            }

            // STOP
            else if (Lifecycle.STOP_EVENT == event.getType()) {

                System.out.println("Stop JMXMP");

                cs.stop();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

So after a day of breaking my head on this issue, I'm now able to use VisualVM on my application.

Answer (score 3):

I created a mvn project based on [Bart von Heukeloms' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11416578/977985) with the needed tomcat-catalina as provided dependency: [jmxmp-lifecycle-listener](https://github.com/Cashlix/jmxmp-lifecycle-listener) 
Just to be plugged in to tomcat's server.xml:
    `<Listener className="javax.management.remote.extension.JMXMPLifecycleListener" port="5555" />`

I don't have enough reputation, otherwise I would have posted this as a comment.